# Truncating all the elements(floats) in a numpy.ndarray

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point

I want to remove digits from all the elements(float) in a numpy array to have a fixed number of digits after the dot, like

```
[ 0.5029503212   0.50408515343  0.50531858897] -> [ 0.5029503   0.50408515  0.50531858]
```

I don't want any rounding of the floating number.

Thank You

Comment: Do you mean you just want to *display* with fewer digits? Have you looked at [`set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe no... no... I want a new array with the specified number of decimal points for future comparison with another array.

Comment: I see - are you aware of the [`allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) function for comparing two arrays with a defined tolerance?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe I am not aware of [allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) function. Let me explore it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) the [allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) helps me to solve this problem. But first we need to convert the numpy ndarray to a list. Here is my code for comparing the two numpy ndarray arrays

> ***center*** and ***center_1***

```
center_a = center.tolist()   # Convert numpy array into list
center_b = center_1.tolist() # Convert numpy array into list
np.allclose(center_b,center_a,rtol=1e-04, atol=1e-04)
```

This returns me true when the two arrays are element-wise equal within a specified tolerance.

Comment: What was the solution you used for doing the actual truncation?